# Change text and style for default title label of action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appbarlayout

I have created a new project with a navigation drawer activity. By default i am getting a title in the action bar as follows.

[image]

I want to change the "Media Lines" text and change the font and size as well. I searched entire project and couldn't find where this title is setting up. I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on activities try this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle("Your title goes here");
//see the other attributes for actionBar for the color and the size
```

and if you are using Fragment:

```
((AppCompatActivity)).getSupportActionBar()).setTilte("your title");
```